# Scroll delay between two divs issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote some dummy code to explain the issue. The problem occurs only if using a mouse, not a touchpad. If you move the mouse pointer into the left div and scrolled down fast to bottom of the div, you will experience a delay until the browser changes the scroll focus into the next div or into body. Is there any solution for this problem? Already tried Scrollintoview() and it didn't help. 
I am using Chrome and Firefox

```css
 body {
      height: 3000px;
      overflow:auto;
    }
    .container {
      height: 1000px;
      width:100%;
      overflow:scroll;
      background:cadetblue;
    }
    .left {
      height:2500px;
      background: bisque;
      width:50%;
      float:left;
      overflow:scroll;
    }
    .right {
      height: 1000px;
      width:50%;
      background:aqua;
      float:right;
    }

    .section {
      background:cornflowerblue;
      width:300px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="left">
        Images
      <div class="right">
        TEXT
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    NEXT section
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if you're talking about the little additional scrolling necessary to activate scroll chaining via [overscroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior) or [scroll snapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Basic_concepts)

Comment: As far as I know this cant be done. Chrome and other browsers require a short pause before they will begin to scroll in the parent. Maybe it is possible if you call `.focus()` on the parent if your scroll all the way down or up in the child

Comment: I believe it is the little additional scrolling that the user do at the end of the element and no scroll chaining occurs to neighbouring scrolling areas. Or it occurs after a certain delay that gives a bad user experince. A user might think that he already is at the page bottom.

Comment: @Wendelin I actullay saw it in a website but i dont recall the name of it, it can be done but i have no idea how :) Already tested .focus() among many other methods but it didn't work. Thank you for your answer tho :)