# Synchronizing scrolling of parent and nested containers in WIndows OS

Tags: javascript, scroll, vertical-scrolling, custom-scrolling

There is markup (see diagram).
[image]

When scrolling a parent container, if there is a nested container under the cursor that also has scrolling, then it first scrolls to the end, and then scrolling of the parent container resumes. On a Mac everything works great, but on Windows there is a problem: after the nested block is scrolled to the end, scrolling of the parent block does not resume. For this to happen, you either need to wait two or three seconds, or slightly move the cursor in any direction, then scrolling of the general container continues again.

How to solve this problem?

I would like the parent container to start scrolling immediately after the child container finishes scrolling. How it works on a Mac.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56008625/scroll-delay-between-two-divs-issue